# Tap into tooltips

Tags: silverlight

I made my own overlay... worked great... but then I noticed that it was appearing off the screen (cut off).

I know silverlight has a tooltip control that auto positions itself on the screen instead of letting itself be cut off.

how can I tap into this control?  or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBlock>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
           <Overlay />  // This is you overlay
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

You can put any content where `<Overlay />` is.  You can also apply this to any control, I just used a TextBlock for my example.

Comment: @zachary: The tooltip will disappear after a few seconds and MS haven't exposed a property to control that which is a shame, dwell time before display and time to remain on screen would be useful properties.  They'll be hardcoded somewhere.